# R geepack: unreasonably large estimates using GEE

Tags: r, logistic-regression, glm, mixed-models, random-effects

I am using `geepack` for R to estimate logistic marginal model by `geeglm()`. But I am getting garbage estimates. They about 16 orders of magnitude too large. However the p-values seems to similar to what I expected. This means that the response essentially becomes a step function. See attached plot[image: Fitted marginal model]

Here is the code that generates the plot:

```
require(geepack)
data = read.csv(url("http://folk.uio.no/mariujon/data.csv"))
fit = geeglm(moden ~ 1 + power, id = defacto, data=data, corstr = "exchangeable", family=binomial)
summary(fit)
plot(moden ~ power, data=data)
x = 0:2500
y = predict(fit, newdata=data.frame(power = x), type="response" )
lines(x,y)
```

Here is the regression table:

```
Call:
geeglm(formula = moden ~ 1 + power, family = binomial, data = data, 
    id = defacto, corstr = "exchangeable")

 Coefficients:
             Estimate   Std.err  Wald Pr(>|W|)    
(Intercept) -7.38e+15  1.47e+15  25.1  5.4e-07 ***
power        2.05e+13  1.60e+12 164.4  < 2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Estimated Scale Parameters:
            Estimate  Std.err
(Intercept) 1.03e+15 1.65e+37

Correlation: Structure = exchangeable  Link = identity 

Estimated Correlation Parameters:
      Estimate  Std.err
alpha    0.196 3.15e+21
Number of clusters:   3   Maximum cluster size: 381
```

Hoping for some help. Thanks!

Kind regards,

Marius

Comment: you're going to need some sort of regularization or shrinkage component. You could do this with a generalized linear mixed model + Bayesian priors on the fixed effect (`MCMCglmm` or `blme` packages), but it will fit the conditional rather than the marginal model ... I don't know offhand how to implement shrinkage in the GEE framework, or whether someone has already done it.

Comment: I have a marginal logistic approach that gives -0.664 for `(Intercept)` and 0.003 for `power`.  Is there interest in my writing it up?

Comment: @swihart : certainly

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the data application?  I am intrigued because I typically work in situations with lots of clusters with just a few observations per cluster -- whereas the one here has 3 clusters and 381 observations on a cluster.

Comment: @swihart there was a biology application. In an experiment, hundreds of individuals were raised in exactly 3 environments. We wanted to study the probability that an individual became mature given the body mass index. But we expected there were correlations induced by the environment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I will give three procedures, each of which is a marginalized random intercept model (MRIM). These MRIMs have coefficients with marginal logistic interpretations and are of smaller magnitude than the GEE:

```
| Model | (Intercept) |  power |  LogL  |
|-------|-------------|--------|--------| 
| `L_N` |       -1.050| 0.00267|  -270.1|
| `LLB` |       -0.668| 0.00343|  -273.8|
| `LPN` |       -1.178| 0.00569|  -266.4|
```

compared to a glm that doesn't account for any correlation, for reference:

```
| Model | (Intercept) |  power |  LogL  |
|-------|-------------|--------|--------| 
|  strt |       -0.207| 0.00216|  -317.1|
```

A marginalized random intercept model (MRIM) is worth exploring because you want a marginal model with exchangeable correlation structure for the clustered data, and that is the type of structure MRIMs exhibit.

The code (especially [R script with comments](https://github.com/swihart/marginal-model-clustered-data/blob/master/R_script_with_comments.R)) and PDFs for literature are in the [GITHUB repo](https://github.com/swihart/marginal-model-clustered-data).  I detail the code and literature down below.

The concept of MRIM has been around since 1999, and some background reading on this is in the [GITHUB repo](https://github.com/swihart/marginal-model-clustered-data).  I suggest reading *Swihart et al 2014* first because it reviews the other papers.

In chronological order --

- `L_N`  *Heagerty (1999)*:  the approach fits a random intercept logistic model with a normally distributed random intercept.  The trick is that the predictor in the random intercept model is nonlinearly parameterized with marginal coefficients so that the resulting marginal model has a marginal logistic interpretation.  Its code is the `lnMLE` R package (not on CRAN, but on Patrick Heagerty's website [here](https://faculty.washington.edu/heagerty/Software/LDA/MLV/)).  This approach is denoted `L_N` in the code to indicate logit (L) on the marginal, no interepretation on conditional scale (_) and a normally (N) distributed random intercept.
- `LLB`  *Wang & Louis (2003)*:  the approach fits a random intercept logistic model with a *bridge* distributed random intercept.  Unlike Heagerty 1999 where the trick is nonlinear-predictor for the random intercept model, the trick is a special random effects distribution (the bridge distribution) that allows both the random intercept model and the resulting marginal model to have a logistic interpretation.  Its code is implemented with `gnlmix4MMM.R` (in the repo) which uses `rmutil` and `repeated` R packages.  This approach is denoted `LLB` in the code to indicate logit (L) on the marginal, logit (L) on the conditional scale and a bridge (B) distributed intercept.
- `LPN`  *Caffo and Griswold (2006)*:  the approach fits a random intercept *probit* model with a normally distributed random intercept, whereas Heagerty 1999 used a *logit* random intercept model.  This substitution makes computations easier and still yields a marginal logit model.  Its code is implemented with `gnlmix4MMM.R` (in the repo) which uses `rmutil` and `repeated` R packages.  This approach is denoted `LPN` in the code to indicate logit (L) on the marginal, probit (P)  on the conditional scale and a normally (N) distributed intercept.
- [*Griswold et al (2013)*](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3865434/): another review / practical introduction.
- *Swihart et al 2014*:  This is a review paper for Heagerty 1999 and Wang & Louis 2003 as well as others and generalizes the MRIM method.  One of the most interesting generalizations is allowing the logistic CDF (equivalently, logit link) in both the marginal and conditional models to instead be a stable distribution that approximates a logistic CDF.  Its code is implemented with `gnlmix4MMM.R` (in the repo) which uses `rmutil` and `repeated` R packages.  I denote this `SSS` in the [R script with comments](https://github.com/swihart/marginal-model-clustered-data/blob/master/R_script_with_comments.R) to indicate stable (S) on the marginal, stable (S) on the conditional scale and a stable (S) distributed intercept.  It is included in the R script but not detailed in this post on SO.

### Prep

```
#code from OP Question: edit `data` to `d` 
require(geepack)
d = read.csv(url("http://folk.uio.no/mariujon/data.csv"))
fit = geeglm(moden ~ 1 + power, id = defacto, data=d, corstr = "exchangeable", family=binomial)
summary(fit)
plot(moden ~ power, data=d)
x = 0:2500
y = predict(fit, newdata=data.frame(power = x), type="response" )
lines(x,y)
#get some starting values from glm():
strt <- coef(glm(moden ~  power, family = binomial, data=d))
strt
#I'm so sorry but these methods use attach()
attach(d)
```

### `L_N` Heagerty (1999)

```
# marginally specifies a logit link and has a nonlinear conditional model
# the following code will not run if lnMLE is not successfully installed.  
# See https://faculty.washington.edu/heagerty/Software/LDA/MLV/
library(lnMLE)
L_N <- logit.normal.mle(meanmodel = moden ~ power,
                        logSigma= ~1,
                        id=defacto,
                        model="marginal",
                        data=d,
                        beta=strt,
                        r=10) 
print.logit.normal.mle(L_N)
```

### Prep for `LLB` and `LPN`

```
library("gnlm")
library("repeated")
source("gnlmix4MMM.R") ## see ?gnlmix; in GITHUB repo 
y <- cbind(d$moden,(1-d$moden))
```

### `LLB` Wang and Louis (2003)

```
LLB  <- gnlmix4MMM(y = y,
                   distribution = "binomial",
                   mixture = "normal",
                   random = "rand",
                   nest = defacto,
                   mu = ~ 1/(1+exp(-(a0 + a1*power)*sqrt(1+3/pi/pi*exp(pmix)) - sqrt(1+3/pi/pi*exp(pmix))*log(sin(pi*pnorm(rand/sqrt(exp(pmix)))/sqrt(1+3/pi/pi*exp(pmix)))/sin(pi*(1-pnorm(rand/sqrt(exp(pmix))))/sqrt(1+3/pi/pi*exp(pmix)))))),
                   pmu = c(strt, log(1)),
                   pmix = log(1))

print("code: 1 -best 2-ok 3,4,5 - problem")
LLB$code
print("coefficients")
LLB$coeff
print("se")
LLB$se
```

### `LPN` Caffo and Griswold (2006)

```
LPN  <- gnlmix4MMM(y = y,
                   distribution = "binomial",
                   mixture = "normal",
                   random = "rand",
                   nest = defacto,
                   mu = ~pnorm(qnorm(1/(1+exp(-a0 - a1*power)))*sqrt(1+exp(pmix)) + rand),
                   pmu = c(strt, log(1)),
                   pmix = log(1))

print("code: 1 -best 2-ok 3,4,5 - problem")
LPN$code
print("coefficients")
LPN$coeff
print("se")
LPN$se
```

### coefficients from 3 approaches:

```
rbind("L_N"=L_N$beta, "LLB" = LLB$coefficients[1:2], "LPN"=LPN$coefficients[1:2])
```

### max log likelihood for 3 models:

```
rbind("L_N"=L_N$logL, "LLB" = -LLB$maxlike, "LPN"=-LPN$maxlike)
```